# Facebook Authentication is not working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I am new to OAuth in asp.net mvc and i tried facebook authentication in my application but it's not working. When i click on Facebook button the page is not redirect to facebook.

Steps i followed for Facebook authentication.

> 1. I created account in facebook for developers.
> 2. Register my application in facebook for developers.
> 3. facebook gives me AppID and AppSecret.
> 4. I put the AppID and AppSecret in the Starutp.cs file (Use facebook authentication).

Now when i click on facebook link it's not redirecting to facebook page.

> **Note**. When i click on facebook link the URL is Change from 
>   `https://localhost:44300/Account/Login`
>
> to
>
> `https://localhost:44300/Account/Login#_=_`

**How to solve it ?**

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

go to facebook developer account and change the Url like this

https://localhost:44300/signin-facebook

Comment: using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
 
//and    your start up //

  app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
            options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
        });